# Multiple slots with the same name -Laravel Blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade

Assuming I want o make a new Blade Component called `multi-step-form`. I want the component to be able to have as many as possible `forms` slots. How do I achieve this.

I tried this: But it didn't work:

```
<!--resources/views/multi-step-form.blade.php -->

    <div>
        @foreach($forms as $form)
           <div class="form"> {{ $form }} </div>
        @endforeach
        <x-next-button> <x-prev-button>


        
    </div>
```

And in the child:

```
<x-multi-step-form>
   <x-slot name="forms" {{ -- or "forms[], none of them work --}}>
      <!-- Some form --->
   <x-slot name="forms">

   <x-slot name="forms" >
      <!-- Some form --->
   <x-slot name="forms">

   <x-slot name="forms">
      <!-- Some form --->
   <x-slot name="forms">
</x-multi-step-form>
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

this is not possible using blade, you can do something like this in vuejs but unfortunately for now it is not possible in laravel blade.

my suggestion would be to make a child component for this component instead of a slot so it would be reusable as much as you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it is impossible to do this. I just tried, and Laravel can't understand you have many component slots with the same name.

Comment: Yeah I eventually came up with a hack involving splitting each instance of  it via delimmiters